# laravel The selected schoolposition id is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, forms, authentication

[i have a problem on my form is says The selected schoolposition id is invalid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFdXH.png)

**The selected schoolposition id is invalid.**

every time i submit it i only refresh and pop up the invalid and i dont know what is the problem on my registercontroller

**this is my controller **

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="schoolposition_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('schoolposition_id') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">


                            <select id="schoolposition_id" type="schoolposition_id"  class="form-control @error('schoolposition_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="schoolposition_id" value="{{ old('schoolposition_id') }}" required autocomplete="schoolposition_id ">


                                @foreach ( $positions as $position)
                                <option value="{{ $position->id }} "> {{ $position->school_position }}</option>                                    
                                    @endforeach
                              </select>


                            @error('schoolposition_id')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**this is my Registercontroller**

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'contact' => ['required', 'numeric ', 'min:11'],
        'department_id' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'schoolposition_id' => ['required','in:user,admin'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
            if ($data['schoolposition_id'] == "admin") {
                return Admin::create([
                    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                    'contact' => $data['contact'],
                    'department_id' => $data['department_id'],
                    'schoolposition_id' => $data['schoolposition_id'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                ]);

            } else {    
                return User::create([
                    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                    'contact' => $data['contact'],
                    'department_id' => $data['department_id'],
                    'schoolposition_id' => $data['schoolposition_id'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Admin.php model**

```
    public function schoolpositions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Schoolposition",'schoolposition_id' , 'id');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Post",'post_id' , 'id');
    }

    //public function students(){
        //return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
   //}

   public function departments()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Department",'department_id' , 'id');
        }



}
```

**Schoolposition.php**

```
 protected $guarded = [];

public function admins()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Admin");
}


    public function dashboards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Dashboard");
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\User");
    }
```

**admin table**

```
Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        //$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('schoolposition_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('contact');
        $table->string('department')->nullable();
        $table->string('schoolposition')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**studentposition table**

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('schoolposition_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->string('department')->nullable();
            $table->string('schoolposition')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Hey, `{{ $position->id }}` and `user` or `admin` are 2 different things. You should probably have the actual ID values in you `in` validation like `in:1,2` instead of `in:user,admin`, because when the form gets posted, the dropdown will have the value and not the innerHTML of the option tag.